# Pass a form field value in the same object

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to send a value to a custom form validator:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            Id: [null],
            Password: ['', [Validators.required]],
            PasswordConfirm: ['', Validators.compose([CustomValidators.expectedMatchingFields(this.myForm.controls.Password.value), Validators.required])]
        });
```

But it doesn't like me sending `"this.myForm.controls.Password.value"`. Is there another way?

It errors with saying `"Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined"`.

Comment: What you mean by "doesn't like me sending"? Is there any error thrown?

Comment: Can you provide more info like what error or how the validator is implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.myForm is null when you call

```
CustomValidators.expectedMatchingFields(this.myForm.controls.Password.value)
```

You can't do this before the this.fb.group() is called.
My advice: create the form without this validator, then update it, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577218/update-validators-in-formcontrol).

I guess this may work

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
 Id: [null],
 Password: ['', [Validators.required]],
 PasswordConfirm: ['']
```

});

```
this.myForm.controls.PasswordConfirm
.setValidators(
Validators.compose(
[CustomValidators.expectedMatchingFields(
  this.myForm.controls.Password.value),
  Validators.required
]));
```